# display error message on front-end asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I display a message on a div `<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>` when I am sending a message from the back-end?

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Signup(Signup signup)
        {
                var result = DBGetCls.GetList("SELECT * FROM Usertable WHERE Email = '{0}' ", signup.Email);
                if (result.Count > 0)
                {
                    object notFound = new { message = "Email has been used!" };
                    return BadRequest(notFound);
                }
```

So my form would look like this:

```
<div id="signup">
    <form asp-action="Signup">

        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label active highlight">Name :</label>
            <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
         .
         .
```

Comment: Have a look at SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

In your frontend MVC controller, you can add errors to the model state. These will be rendered in the validation summary. So when the backend answers with `BadRequest`, add an error manually.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyNameInViewModelToBeHighlighted", 
    "Error message to be shown in validation summary");
```

Some teams also build custom infrastructure to wrap the backend calls, catch any errors, extract the error message, and add it to the ModelState automatically.

See also [What is the ModelState?](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/)